# How to get the Device Resolution in Wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, screen-resolution

I want to set some icons in my app according to device screen resolution like wxga or wvga. I saw in many links like App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor or Application.Current.RootVisual.RenderSize.  But I can only access App.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth or Height. These always say as 480x800 even though I am running the app in wxga Device. How do i know the resolution correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 only supports one resolution(800*480). Are you asking about Windows Phone 8? Please a look at [Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) . Here is the ResolutionHelper class you can use.

```
    public enum Resolutions { WVGA, WXGA, HD720p };

    public static class ResolutionHelper
    {
       private static bool IsWvga
       {
          get
          {
             return App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 100;
          }
       }

       private static bool IsWxga
       {
          get 
          { 
             return App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 160; 
          }
       }

       private static bool Is720p
       {
          get 
          { 
             return App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 150; 
          }
       }

       public static Resolutions CurrentResolution
       {
          get
          {
             if (IsWvga) return Resolutions.WVGA;
             else if (IsWxga) return Resolutions.WXGA;
             else if (Is720p) return Resolutions.HD720p;
             else throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown resolution");
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: I am using same code but I cannot access ScaleFactor. Yes, I am targetting wp7.1. But the app will run on wp8 device also right. So I accordingly want to set some icons

Comment: Windows Phone 7 can't get Windows Phone 8 resolution. It's a simulator of WP7 on WP8 to run your app. It's better to upgrade your app.

Comment: If I run the app in wp8 Simulator , why doesn't the resolution change?

Comment: Because your app doesn't know it is running on WP8, and it can't change itself to fit the screen. WP8 has a virtual machine (simulator) to run WP7 apps.

Answer (score 1):

You Target your app for **Windows Phone 7.1** , so you should update your app to target **windows phone 8.0 OS** by **clicking right** on your project and **Upgrade to Windows Phone 8.0**

Comment: Yes, I am targetting wp7.1 but i use the APP TO RUN IN WP8 AS WELL. so i need to know the device resolution